# Changing default JUnit method stubs to create in Eclipse dialog

Tags: eclipse, junit

When you select "New > JUnit Test Case" in Eclipse, you get a dialog box prompting you for parameters for the new test case you are creating, such as the source folder, package, name, superclass, etc.

One section in this dialog is labeled "Which method stubs would you like to create?", followed by checkboxes for setUpBeforeClass(), tearDownAfterClass(), setUp(), tearDown(), and constructor.  There seems to be default settings for these checkboxes, apparently based on the values from last time you used the dialog.

But some of these checkboxes are grayed out (it seems to differ between Eclipse release).  When the value is wrong, there is no apparent way to change it.  For example, if the constructor checkbox is checked but grayed out, there is no way I know of to change it.  It just generates a JUnit test case source file with a constructor that I have to delete.

Where are those defaults stored?  I have grepped through the Eclipse .metadata file in my workspace and haven't been able to find them.

Answer (score 0):

The settings for this dialog are in a `dialog_settings.xml` file in the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.junit` folder.

In the XML they will be in a 'JUnitWizards' section.

The key values are 'NewTestCaseCreationWizardPage.USE_xxx' where xxx is SETUP, TEARDOWN, SETUPCLASS, TEARDOWNCLASS, CONSTRUCTOR.

It is the 'New JUnit 3 test' / 'new JUnit 4 test' toggle which controls which methods are enabled.

The main source code reference for this is `org.eclipse.jdt.junit.wizards.NewTestCaseWizardPageOne`